# PHP regex to clean a specific string from URLs only

Tags: php, regex, url

Any regex ninjas out there to come up with a PHP solution to cleaning the tag  from any http/url , but leaving the tag in the rest of the text?

eg:

```
the word <cite>printing</cite> is in http://www.thisis<cite>printing</cite>.com
```

should become:

```
the word <cite>printing</cite> is in http://www.thisisprinting.com
```

Comment: Quite a difficult task, have you elaborated something ?

Comment: Matching url's isn't easy, human error like not putting a space after a period `.` for sentences can play havoc. What parts of the url can you guarantee to be there ie `https?://|www`. If you can guarantee some string will exist, then removing tags wouldn't be hard

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
<?php
//a callback function wrapper for strip_tags
function strip($matches){
    return strip_tags($matches[0]);
}

//the string
$str = "the word <cite>printing<cite> is in http://www.thisis<cite>printing</cite>.com";
//match a url and call the strip callback on it
$str = preg_replace_callback("/:\/\/[^\s]*/", 'strip', $str);

//prove that it works
var_dump(htmlentities($str));
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/XiPcs9

Answer (score 1):

Your appropriate regex for this substitution could be:

```
#(https?://)(.*?)<cite>(.*?)</cite>([^\s]*)#s
```

1. `s` flag to match in all newlines.
2. Using `lazy` selection between tags for being accurate not to escape more similar tags

Snippet:

```
<?php
$str = "the word <cite>printing<cite> is in http://www.thisis<cite>printing</cite>.com";
$replaced = preg_replace('#(https?://)(.*?)<cite>(.*?)</cite>([^\s]*)#s', "$1$2$3$4", $str);
echo $replaced;

// Output: the word <cite>printing<cite> is in http://www.thisisprinting.com
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/yoC7PO)

Comment: Instead of using `(.*?)` I would suggest using `([^\s]*?)`. With the way you are doing it, if the url was the first part of the string without cite tags, subsequent `<cite>` tags would be removed from later text.

Comment: That's a great start - @JonathanKuhn's addition is priceless. How would I trap a second (third etc) instance of the string in the URL?

eg: https://<cite>app</cite>leid.<cite>app</cite>le.com

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can identify URLs from your text you can:

```
$str = 'http://www.thisis<cite>printing</cite>.com';
$str = preg_replace('~</?cite>~i', "", $str);
echo $str;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
http://www.thisisprinting.com
```

Comment: @HamZa: Assuming `$str = 'http://www.thisis<cite>printing</cite>.com';` not the full HTML text.

Comment: you omitted `printing` here but he wants the output to be `http://www.thisisprinting.com`